# Setting up Static IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, static-ip

This question is for an internal home network. I purchased a new PC and installed Windows 10. By default, both TCP v4 and v6 are enabled, and run in DHCP mode.

I am familiar with configuring the modem/router to assign DHCP above a certain range (say, 192.168.1.100), and keep the static IP addresses below that
(for example, 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.99).

Q1. For IPv6, does it also operate in a similar way? i.e. Can most router/modems also reserve an IPv6 range for dymamic DHCP? If so, what is the recommended IPv6 dhcp range for a home network?

Q2. As stated, both protocol versions are enabled, If I change TCPv4 for static, MUST I also set TCPv6 for static (or can i keep v4 static and v6 dynamic) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most home networks (and many office networks as well) use SLAAC and don't assign IPv6 addresses through DHCPv6. As far as I know the home routers that do support address assignment through DHCPv6 can be configured to assign addresses from a specific range, but there is no recommended range for that. The IPv6 address space is so huge that it doesn't really matter.

IPv4 and IPv6 are separate protocols, so assigning a static address to one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: Is there a concept of non-routable IP addresses for IPv6? Similar to how in IPv4 the range 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 can be used for internal networks.

Comment: Yes, there is. It's called Unique Local Addresses (ULA). Because NAT isn't used with IPv6 it's really for internal use only. Instead of using NAT it's used on its own on closed networks, or side-by-side with globally routable addresses on networks that are connected to the internet.

Comment: wow sorry totally forgot about this question. accepting this answer nearly 3 years later :-)